# Why won't the context-state of my popup reset when i close the Popup?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am currently working on a project where I am implementing custom popups over a Leaflet map. Data for said popups are stored in an overarching context, and this context along with its setter is passed to the component in question. When closing the popup I have a handleClose function, that is supposed to reset the array to clean the data, but this doesnt happen.

In the below example is an exerpt of my code. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I'm sure its something basic. If I check the array directly after the call to setTravelTime, it is still populated, regardless of the if-check.

**Popup.tsx**

```
export default function TravelTimesPopup() {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const { setShowMapLayerPopup, mapCircle, travelTime, setTravelTime } = useAppContext();

function handleClose() {
    setShowMapLayerPopup(false);
    if (travelTime.length > 0) setTravelTime([]);
    mapCircle.clearLayers();
}
return travelTime.length > 0 ? (
    <PopupContainer handleClose={() => handleClose()}>
// implementation...
    </PopupContainer>
```

Comment: It is difficult to find what is going wrong with only this code excerpt

Comment: Hi @TurtleneckKing, According to my view, In `handleClose()` when you call `setShowMapLayerPopup(false)` the control left this `TravelTimePopup` and next won't get executed.
Try debugging to pin point the issue.

Comment: I guess `travelTime` is a state variable. `If I check the array directly after the call to setTravelTime, it is still populated`. That is the correct behavior of a state variable, it will change only with the next render.